# Postgres altered password for user, but old password still works, new one does not

Tags: postgresql, passwords, alter

I altered password for a user. I thought there would be a flush privileges command like in MySQL but there was not. So I restarted the server `sudo /etc/init.d/postgres restart`, however old password still active.

What do I have to do to make my alter user password command to stick?

On version 9.3.10

Comment: Can you show the command that you used to change password?

Comment: `alter user mmuser set password to "test"`

Comment: it's wrong. run `ALTER USER mmuser PASSWORD 'test';`

Comment: Unlike MySQL, there is no "flush privileges" required in PostgreSQL. A password change is immediate.

Answer (score 2):

> alter user mmuser set password to "test"

This SQL statement should have raised an error.

```
    ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "password"
    SQL state: 42704
```

Also, in SQL, strings take single quotes.

[Current docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html) for the syntax, excerpted below.

```
ALTER USER name [ [ WITH ] option [ ... ] ]

where option can be:

    [snip]
    PASSWORD 'password'
```

So you needed

```
alter user mmuser password 'test';
```